# How can you prove that a conditional bivariate Gaussian is a univariate Gaussian?

Tags: conditional-expectation, gaussian, bivariate-distributions

Is there a way to prove that a bivariate Gaussian becomes a univariate Gaussian when conditioned on one of the two variables?

Comment: $(X,Y)$ conditioned on $Y$ is still a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$. In particular, it's not a number. Or do you mean something else by univariate Gaussian?

Comment: If we have a Gaussian distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{x}|\boldsymbol{\mu}, \mathbf{\Sigma})$ and $\mathbf{x} = [x_1, x_2]^\intercal$, I am talking about $\mathcal{N}(x_1|x_2, \boldsymbol{\mu}, \mathbf{\Sigma})$

Comment: I don't see how that invalidates my comment or answers my question.

Comment: By univariate Gaussian I mean that $\mathcal{N}(x_1|x_2, \boldsymbol{\mu}, \mathbf{\Sigma})$ will be a one-dimensional distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the density of a jointly Gaussian vector $(X,Y)$

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_X\sigma_Y\sqrt{1-\rho^2)}}\exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left[ \frac{(x-\mu_X)^2}{\sigma_X^2}-2\rho\frac{(x-\mu_X)(y-\mu_Y)}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y}   +\frac{(y-\mu_Y)^2}{\sigma_Y^2} \right]  \right\}=$$

$$=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_X\sigma_Y\sqrt{1-\rho^2)}}\exp\left\{- \frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)} \frac{(x-\mu_X)^2}{\sigma_X^2}  \right\}\cdot\exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left[ \frac{(y-\mu_Y)^2}{\sigma_Y^2}-2\rho\frac{(x-\mu_X)(y-\mu_Y)}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y}    \right]  \right\}=$$

Now sum and subtract the following quantity in the argument of the second exp

$$\frac{\rho^2(x-\mu_X)^2}{\sigma_X^2}$$

...and after some (easy) algebraic manipulations you get

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=f_X(x)\cdot f_{Y|X}(y|x)$$

Where

$$X\sim N(\mu_X;\sigma_X^2)$$

$$(Y|X=x)\sim N\left[\mu_Y+\rho\frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_X}(x-\mu_X);\sigma_Y^2(1-\rho^2)   \right]$$

Observe that if you set $\rho=0$ (uncorrelation) the joint density becomes

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=f_X(x)\cdot f_Y(y)$$

meaning that, in this model, uncorrelation and independence are equivalent.